# Pixelart Snowfall animation in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class

Hello im making a Snowfall animation in Java, but i have a few problems. The Snowflakes should be rectangles which have a random gray color between 100-255.I need to use a grid with array of arrays and once per call to the draw method, a snowflake can change columns by either -1, 0, or +1 if it falls down (changes the row) and the column in the new row is not already occupied.  My problem now is, that The snowflakes arent moving downwards and so they just go from left to right in the first row and after a few seconds they stop getting drawn.

This is my code for the grid class. And in the updateSnowflakes method is the not working snowflake movement.

```java
public class Grid {

    private static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 800;
    private static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = 800;
    public int GRID_HEIGHT = CANVAS_HEIGHT;
    public int GRID_WIDTH = CANVAS_WIDTH;
    public int SNOWFLAKE_WIDTH = GRID_WIDTH / GRID_WIDTH;
    public int SNOWFLAKE_HEIGHT = GRID_HEIGHT / GRID_HEIGHT;


    public GridView[][] elements;


    public Grid(int GRID_HEIGHT, int GRID_WIDTH, int SNOWFLAKE_HEIGHT, int SNOWFLAKE_WIDTH) {
        this.GRID_HEIGHT = GRID_HEIGHT;
        this.GRID_WIDTH = GRID_WIDTH;
        this.SNOWFLAKE_HEIGHT = SNOWFLAKE_HEIGHT;
        this.SNOWFLAKE_WIDTH = SNOWFLAKE_WIDTH;
        elements = new GridView[GRID_WIDTH][GRID_HEIGHT];
        for (int y = 0; y < elements.length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < elements[y].length; x++) {
                elements[y][x] = new GridView(y * SNOWFLAKE_HEIGHT, x * SNOWFLAKE_WIDTH);
            }
        }

    }

    public void drawSnowflakes() {
        for (int i = 0; i < elements[0].length; i++) {
            boolean shouldDrawSnowflake = Math.random() < (1f / 80f);
            Random random = new Random();
            int low = 100;
            int high = 256;
            int g = random.nextInt(high - low) + low;
            Color snowflakeColor = new Color(g, g, g, g);

            if (shouldDrawSnowflake && !elements[i][0].hasSnowflake) {
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(i,0, SNOWFLAKE_WIDTH, SNOWFLAKE_HEIGHT, snowflakeColor);
                elements[i][0].rectangle = rectangle;
                elements[i][0].hasSnowflake = true;
                rectangle.draw();


            }
        }
    }


    public void updateSnowflakes() {

        for (int y = 0; y < elements.length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < elements[y].length; x++) {
                GridView gridcell = elements[x][y];
                if (gridcell.hasSnowflake) {
                    if (y + 1 > CANVAS_HEIGHT) {
                        return;
                    }
                    Random random = new Random();
                    if (x + random.nextInt(3) - 1 < GRID_WIDTH || x + random.nextInt(3) - 1 > GRID_WIDTH) {
                        return;
                    }
                    GridView nextGridCell;
                    nextGridCell=elements[x+ random.nextInt(3)-1][y+1];
                    if (nextGridCell.hasSnowflake == true) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is in this line of updateSnowFlakes():

```
Random random = new Random(); 
if (x + random.nextInt(3) - 1 < GRID_WIDTH || x + random.nextInt(3) - 1 > GRID_WIDTH) {
                        return;
}
```

I believe this is supposed to end the function if the new x would cause the snowflake to go off the grid.
However, it instead ends the function whenever the new x is greater than or less than `GRID_WIDTH`.

This means that the function will only ever continue if the new x = `GRID_WIDTH`.

To fix this, try changing it to:

```
Random random = new Random(); 
if (x + random.nextInt(3) - 1 < 0 || x + random.nextInt(3) - 1 > GRID_WIDTH) {
                        return;
}
```